# Display all SOL transfers from one Address to Another. Both addresses are specified

Tags: web3.js, javascript

I am very new to JS and Solana. I am trying to show the total amount of SOL that has been transferred from Address_1 to Address_2.

When trying the script below, I get:

`Total SOL received from ADDRESS_2: 0 SOL`

Obviously I have sent some SOL between the addresses (both Mainnet and Devnet) so it should be giving me an amount.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Thank you!

```
async function getTransactionsBySender(receiverAddress, senderAddress, customRpcUrl) {
    const connection = new Connection(customRpcUrl, 'confirmed');
    const receiverPublicKey = new PublicKey(receiverAddress);

    const tokenAccounts = await connection.getParsedTokenAccountsByOwner(receiverPublicKey, {
        programId: new PublicKey("TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb"),
    });

    let totalSolReceivedFromSender = 0;

    for (const accountInfo of tokenAccounts.value) {
        const ownerAddress = new PublicKey(accountInfo.account.owner);
        
        if (ownerAddress.equals(new PublicKey(senderAddress))) {
            const lamports = accountInfo.account.lamports;
            totalSolReceivedFromSender += lamports;
        }
    }

    // Convert the total lamports to SOL
    totalSolReceivedFromSender = totalSolReceivedFromSender / 1000000000;

    console.log(`Total SOL received from ${senderAddress}: ${totalSolReceivedFromSender} SOL`);
}

getTransactionsBySender(receiverAddress, senderAddress, customRpcUrl).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're fetching in your code is the token accounts belonging to `receiverAddress` and checking if they're owned by `senderAddress` (which they never can be). What you want to do instead, is fetch the **transaction** involving your sender and recipient and then checking if a transfer happened from `senderAddress` to `receiverAddress`. There isn't a direct way to do it, so I'd suggest the following:

- Fetch all parsed transactions related to sender `senderAddress`. You can use `connection.getConfirmedSignaturesForAddress2` to first get the sigs related to `senderAddress` and then use `connection.getParsedTransactions`. Notice how I used the call to get *parsed* transactions.
- Since we're dealing with parsed transactions, they return [`ParsedTransactionWithMeta`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/types/ParsedTransactionWithMeta.html) as their type, which as part of it's `meta` field has an array of `preBalances` and `postBalances`. These tell you the amount of lamports in each transaction account before and after the transaction is processed. Based on these, you can check if 1) `recipientAddress` is in the accounts used by the transaction and 2) the `senderAddress`'s balance decreased by the same amount as `recipientAddress` increased.

Based on these, you should be able to come up with the code to do what you want. :)